# Creating Directory (named Today Date) and Writing Log Files(named CompanyName) for Each Company in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, logging, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.2 for a project I'm doing. I want to log files differently as the method provided in the Laravel (a big file or daily based file).

The approach I want to follow is that

1. There would be created a directory for each day instead of a file for each day as laravel's Log::useDailyFile() method provides.
2. Each directory would contains the log file for each company, and the log file would be the Company Name + id.

I've created different log files for each company using following code:

```
if (Config::get('app.log') != 'daily') {
    Log::useFiles(storage_path().'/logs/laravel.log',    Config::get('app.log_level'));
}
else {
    $companyId = isset($_COOKIE['companyId'])?$_COOKIE['companyId']:null;
    $company = Company::where('id', $companyId)->get();

    $companyName = $company[0]->name;
    $companyName = str_replace(' ', '_', $companyName);
    Config::get('app.log_max_files'), Config::get('app.log_level'));
    Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/'.$companyName.'_'.$companyId.'-laravel.log', Config::get('app.log_max_files'), Config::get('app.log_level'));
}
```

But these are getting stored in the same folder name 'logs'.

My basic question is that how can I create a folder daily and then save each company's log file of that particular date in the date folder. i.e today it is 14-12-2015, this should create a folder named '14-12-2015' and should save log files in it as 'ComapnyA_01.log' and 'Comapny_02.log' in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should run a [cron job](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) and mention the run time as per your wish (1 time in 24 hours).

The cron should point to a path and it should lead a controller which will does the following works.

**Step 1 :**  Create a directory on current date

```
File::makeDirectory('/path/to/directory', 0775, true);
```

Here's the [reference link](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/147/creating-a-directory)

**Step 2 :** Write a Log

```
$companyName = 'Retrieve from your DB';
Log::info($companyName);
```

Here's the [official doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#logging) to refer it